# Issue instantiating GeoIPService

Tags: java, web-services

I'm using very similar code to what I've found online, but I'm getting the error "Can't instantiate the type GeoIPService". I found the same issue in another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31829598/cannot-initiate-the-type-geoipservice-in-java) but it was never answered.

```
import net.webservicex.www.GeoIP;
import net.webservicex.www.GeoIPService;
import net.webservicex.www.GeoIPServiceSoap;;

public class CountryFinder
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        GeoIPService service = new GeoIPService();  // "Cannot instaniate the type GeoServiceIP"
        GeoIPServiceSoap port = service.getGeoIPServiceSoap();
        System.out.print(port.getGeoIP("1.1.1.1").getCountryName());
    }
}
```

UPDATE: For anyone using the same classes, the issue was solved by instantiating GeoIPServiceLocator instead of GeoIPService.

Comment: Are you sure `GeoIPService` is not an interface? You would have to instantiate an implementation of it if it were.

Comment: Is it actually yeah, would I need to create a class that implements GeoIPService and then instantiate that in CountryFinder?

Comment: If you wanted to define the methods within `GeoIPService`, yes, but I'm assuming you want to use an imported class that already uses the interface. I don't know where you got those imports, but if there is any documentation for them, then I'd recommend checking it to see what classes implement that interface.

Comment: Ah yes I got what I wanted by instantiating another class that was implementing GeoIPService, thank you so much!

Comment: Well then I'll post it as an answer, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GeoIPService` is an interface, not a class, therefore you must instantiate an implementation of it, not the interface itself.

Incorrect:
`GeoIPService service = new GeoIPService();`

Correct:
`GeoIPService service = new ClassThatImplementsGeoIPService();`